# Optional throw requires throws declaration for NPE

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

When throwing an exception for a nullable optional i'm getting a compile error, requiring me to catch or declare the exception as thrown, but an NPE is a runtime exception that doesn't need to be caught. So basically the orElseThrow behaviour is not the same as throwing an exception pre java 8.
Is this a feature or a bug? any thoughts?

this doesn't compile:

```
protected String sendTemplate() {
    String template = getTemplate();
    return Optional.ofNullable(template).orElseThrow(() -> {
        throw new NullPointerException("message");
    });

}
```

this does:

```
protected String sendTemplate() {
    String template = getTemplate();
    if (template == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("message");
    }
    else return template;
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to _throw_ an exception inside `orElseThrow`. You're supposed to _supply_ an exception to be thrown. `orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("message"))`

Comment: I'm not getting a compilation error with this code. (though it should be `return new NullPointerException("message");` not `throw...`)

Comment: just replace the word throw with the word return :)

Comment: what does `orElseThrow` take as input? a `Supplier`? what is the definition of a `Supplier`?...

Comment: @Eran [you’re likely using a new compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055191/2711488)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
protected String sendTemplate() {
    String template = getTemplate();
    return Optional.ofNullable(template).orElseThrow(() -> {
        throw new NullPointerException("message");
    });
}
```

by this:

```
protected String sendTemplate() {
    String template = getTemplate();
    return Optional.ofNullable(template).orElseThrow(() -> {
        return new NullPointerException("message"); // <--- RETURN here
    });
}
```

The method [orElseThrow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) requires a supplier (ie something creating an exception). You must not throw an exception, just creating it.

Answer (score 5):

The `Supplier` passed to `orElseThrow` is supposed to return the constructed exception, which is relevant to the generic signature of that method, which declares to throw what the supplier returned. Since your supplier does not return a value, the JDK 8 `javac` infers `Throwable` and requires the caller of `orElseThrow` to handle it. Newer compilers conveniently infer `RuntimeException` in that situation and don’t produce an error.

Still, the correct usage would be

```
protected String sendTemplate1() {
    String template = getTemplate();
    return Optional.ofNullable(template)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("message"));
}
```

But this is an overuse of `Optional` anyway. You should simply use

```
protected String sendTemplate() {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(getTemplate(), "message");
}
```

See [`requireNonNull(T, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) and [`requireNonNull(T, Supplier<String>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.util.function.Supplier-).